# How to use R Shiny to download file from a Box URL (not from server)

Tags: r, shiny

I have an Excel (.xslx) file stored at a Box location, with fixed URL. How do I code in R Shiny to download this Excel file into the server for further manipulation and usage? All the examples I have found so far are either to download some file already on the server, or to download a displayed table on a URL into an .csv file. The downloadHandler does not seem to have this capability. Below is what is have in mind, but not sure how to proceed further. Thanks.

```r
library(shiny)

boxURL <- "https://*****.box.com/s/*****************"

app <- list(
  ui = fluidPage(
    titlePanel(""),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        downloadButton("downloadFile", label = "Download Excel from Box URL")
      ),
      mainPanel(h6("Table In Downloaded Excel File", align = "center"))
    )
  ),

  server = function(input, output) {  
    output$downloadFile<- downloadHandler(
      filename <- function() {
      #code to download Excel file to filename
      ...

      },

      content <- function(file) {
        # the content is a typical table in Excel.
      },
      contentType = "excel"
    )
  }
)
```

Comment: Please add some more information.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, Raj. I have added what I am thinking of doing.

Answer (score 0):

In order to download contents from https://www.box.com, you will probably need authentication. Usually, it is best to use a client or interface for such usecases. A quick google search revealed the follwing package, that provides an R interface for the box.com API:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/boxr/vignettes/boxr.html.

Comment: Thanks, Gregor. I read the link you gave and followed the instruction. However, my Box URL is accessed from within an organization which I am already automatically authorized to access. It is not a personal Box account so I am not able to the client and interface setup. As long my R Shiny app is run from within this organization, the Box URL is accessible to that local computer. So, I am treating this URL as any public downloadable file link, i.e. download a file directly from the URL. Can any of R Shiny functions do that?

Comment: @TristanTran boxr has new support for this type of Service account, see [`box_auth_service()`](https://r-box.github.io/boxr/articles/boxr-app-service.html)

Answer (score 0):

Using an HTTP GET request and the `write_disk()` function to deliver content within the download handler works.

In your server callback:

```r
output$downloadFile <- downloadHandler(

  filename = function() {
    # code to define filename
    paste0("filename", ".xlsx")
  },

  content = function(file) {
    # Perform a HTTP GET request to your Box URL and download the 
    # resulting file to a file named "filename.xlsx"
    GET(boxURL, write_disk(file))
  },

  contentType = "excel"

)
```

Note that this only works if your URL is to the *file download*, not to the Box page showing the file. This means if you visit that URL on your browser, it should prompt the download of your desired file.